# Streaming data to web from google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to publish the data from my google cloud to a website. I have created a script which dynamically uploads the data from my device to google cloud. The issue i am facing is how can i publish the data from google cloud to a website. I just need to display the data which i have on google cloud.

Comment: You need public link to your data in cloud storage?

Comment: Make you bucket public

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, you can [make your bucket public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public) and just have your application fetch the object via an HTTP request or even just post the link in your website depending on what you are trying to do. If you don’t want to make your bucket public, or you just want a more personalized approach, you can just create your own application that retrieves data from the bucket by using the GCS client library. Here you can find some code samples on how you could [download objects from a GCS bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#code-samples) from within your own application.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way when you upload some data(lets say some images) you make the storage bucket public. After making it public you will get link of each object you upload. So, when you are uploading a image in gcp storage save them with continuous names(ex-1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg...). So you will get a link of each object in the format(https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket_name/1.jpg). 
So when you will be working on its front-end you just need to set a loop and all the data would be streamed to web.

If there's a good way then please suggest.

Thank you